How to match the table from XML to XSL
I want to populate a table with its correct XMl tags...I have already written the code with the tags but somehow it is not populating the table with data when I take the XML and XSl to then trasnform it to HTML...I beilive I am missing an argument to call the table like table ID
I am grateful for any input :)
Here is the code:
XSL code
<div class="table">
   <table border="1">
       <h3>NLS Alert details</h3>
           <tr>
             <th>NLS "Record ID"</th>
             <th>Name</th>
             <th>NLS Alert Description</th>
             <th>AML DD Comments</th>
             <th>AFC Comments</th>
           </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="NewDataSet/_x0039_c07da72-63fc-45fe-9ab7-4c787b1e6984">
<xsl:if test="normalize-space(AMLNLSRecordID) or normalize-space(AMLNLSAlertName) or normalize-space(AMLNLSAlertDescription) or normalize-space(AMLDDAFCComments) or normalize-space(AMLAFCComments)">
                            
    <tr>
       <td>
       <xsl:value-of select="AMLNLSRecordID"/>
       </td>
           <td>
       <xsl:value-of select="AMLNLSAlertName"/>
       </td>
       <td>
       <xsl:value-of select="AMLNLSAlertDescription"/>
       </td>
       <td>
       <xsl:value-of select="AMLDDAFCComments"/>
       </td>
       <td>
           <xsl:value-of select="AMLAFCComments"/>
       </td>
       </tr>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
          </table>
           </div>
</div>

XML code
<Table TableId="NLSAlertDetailsTable">
    <TableRow RowNumber="1">
      <AMLNLSRecordID>1</AMLNLSRecordID>
      <AMLNLSAlertName>Name 1 Surname 1</AMLNLSAlertName>
      <AMLNLSAlertDescription>1</AMLNLSAlertDescription>
      <AMLDDAFCComments>1</AMLDDAFCComments>
      <AMLAFCComments>Test</AMLAFCComments>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow RowNumber="2">
      <AMLNLSRecordID>2</AMLNLSRecordID>
      <AMLNLSAlertName>Name 2 Surname 2</AMLNLSAlertName>
      <AMLNLSAlertDescription>2</AMLNLSAlertDescription>
      <AMLDDAFCComments>2</AMLDDAFCComments>
      <AMLAFCComments>Test 1</AMLAFCComments>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow RowNumber="3">
      <AMLNLSRecordID>3</AMLNLSRecordID>
      <AMLNLSAlertName>Name 3 Surname 3</AMLNLSAlertName>
      <AMLNLSAlertDescription>3</AMLNLSAlertDescription>
      <AMLDDAFCComments>3</AMLDDAFCComments>
      <AMLAFCComments>Test 2</AMLAFCComments>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow RowNumber="4">
      <AMLNLSRecordID>4</AMLNLSRecordID>
      <AMLNLSAlertName>Name 4 Surname 4</AMLNLSAlertName>
      <AMLNLSAlertDescription>4</AMLNLSAlertDescription>
      <AMLDDAFCComments>4</AMLDDAFCComments>
      <AMLAFCComments>Test 3</AMLAFCComments>
    </TableRow>
  </Table>

The problem is above

Please post a [mcve], not snippets of code taken out of context.

Note that your XML does not have an element named NewDataSet, so your instruction <xsl:for-each select="NewDataSet/_x0039_c07da72-63fc-45fe-9ab7-4c787b1e6984"> selects nothing.

If i put the tableid in the select argument, will it work? I am really new to this

If you have multiple tables, you can use the TableId in a predicate to select the correct one. -- P.S.  I don't think you are ready to ask questions here. You need to have a minimal understanding of how XSLT works, otherwise you won't be able to understand the provided answers. XSLT is not intuitive, you can't wing it by trial-and-error. Spend an hour or two with a book or a tutorial first.

I just tweaked your .xsl
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output encoding="utf-8" method="html" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <head>
            <style>
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="table">
                <table border="1">
                    <h3>NLS Alert details</h3>
                    <tr>
                        <th>NLS "Record ID"</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>NLS Alert Description</th>
                        <th>AML DD Comments</th>
                        <th>AFC Comments</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="Table/TableRow">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="AMLNLSRecordID"/>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="AMLNLSAlertName"/>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="AMLNLSAlertDescription"/>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="AMLDDAFCComments"/>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="AMLAFCComments"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </div>
            <script>
</script>
        </body>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

And it produced this result;

Is this the result you were looking for?
--I removed the logic test to check if a node has a value, unless you are expecting NULL in your source xml?

I have tried your solution...no dice. Thank you very much for your effort!
I am just stuck trying to get the data from the XML to XSL to fit it in the NLS table....I will keep trying!

Have a look at this
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_intro.asp
XPath is very logical, in your .xsl your for-each statement isn't pointing to anything within your source .xml.
The for-each sets the level at which XPath can see the various nodes in your xml data.  I set mine to Table/TableRow so that each TableRow of your xml is transformed by the .xsl
--Is it possible that your live data set will contain multiple tables?

Hey Nick, thanks for your input.
Yes my data has multiple tables.....I will look at w3schools and try to get an answer
